# find missing value between to tables in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

> I have two tables  with a common field I want to find all the the
> items(user_id's) which present in the first table but not in the second.

```
Table1(user_id,...)
Table2(userid,...)
```

user_id in  Table1 and Table2 are FKs pointing to same column in another table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

session.query(Table1.user_id).outerjoin(Table2).filter(Table2.user_id == None)

Comment: Hi Jisson, I would recommend against outerjoin, as I don't really believe it's going to do what you want. An outerjoin will return every record from Table1 regardless of whether there is an entry in table2...

Answer (score 0):

This is untested as I'm still new to SQLAlchemy, but I think it should push you in the right direction:

```
table2 = session.query(Table2.user_id).subquery()
result = session.query(Table1).filter(Table1.user_id.notin_(table2))
```

my guess is this type of approach would result in the following SQL:

```
SELECT table1.* FROM table1 WHERE table1.user_id NOT IN (SELECT table2.user_id FROM table2)
```